# Prevent Nginx from changing host

Tags: django, nginx, networking, server, ngrok

I am building an application which is right now working on localhost. I have my entire dockerized application up and running at **https://localhost/**.
HTTP request is being redirected to HTTPS

My nginx configuration in docker-compose.yml is handling all the requests as it should.

I want my application accessible from anywhere hence i tried using Ngrok to route the request to my localhost. Actually i have a mobile app in development so need a local server for apis.

Now, when i enter ngrok's url like abc123.ngrok.io in the browser, the nginx converts it to **https://localhost/**. That works for my host system's browser, as my web app is working there only, but when i open the same in my mobile emulator. It doesn't work.

I am newbie to nginx. Any suggestions will be welcomed.
Here's my nginx configuration.

nginx.conf

```
upstream web {
    ip_hash;
    server web:443;
}

# Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# for https requests
server {

    # Pass request to the web container
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://web/;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/mysite/;
    }
    
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;

    # SSL properties
    # (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/certs/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/certs/localhost.key;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;    
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
}
```

This configuration i got from a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you set redirection from every HTTP request to HTTPS:

```
# Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

You are using `$server_name` variable here, so every `/some/path?request_string` HTTP request to your app would be redirected to `https://localhost/some/path?request_string`. At least change the `return` directive to

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

Check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/706438/what-is-the-difference-between-nginx-variables-host-http-host-and-server-na) question for information about difference between `$host` and `$server_name` variables.

If these are your only server blocks in your nginx config, you can safely remove the `server_name localhost;` directive at all, those blocks still remains the default blocks for all incoming requests on 80 and 443 TCP ports.

The second one, if you are using self-signed certificate for `localhost` be ready for browser complains about mismatched certificate (issued for `localhost`, appeared at `abc123.ngrok.io`). If it doesn't break your mobile app, its ok, but if it is, you can get the certificate for your `abc123.ngrok.io` domain from Lets Encrypt for free after you start your ngrok connection, check [this](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/) page for available ACME clients and options. Or you can disable HTTPS at all if it isn't strictly requred for your debug process, just use this single `server` block:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    # Pass request to the web container
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://web/;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/mysite/;
    }
}
```

Of course this should not be used in production, only for debugging.

And the last one. I don't see any sense encrypting traffic between nginx and `web` containers inside docker itself, especially if you already setup HTTP-to-HTTPS redirection with nginx. It gives you nothing in the terms of security but only some extra overhead. Use plain HTTP protocol on port 80 for communications between nginx and `web` container:

```
upstream web {
    ip_hash;
    server web:80;
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer, that's definitely helpful. Wont be able to check that right now. Will upvote if it did work.

Comment: Changed as you suggested. Though i need HTTPS so only replaced $server_name. Still going to the ngrok url changes to localhost automatically.

Comment: Also, even after using only single server block for http. It still redirects me to localhost. I know its not that relevant but still.

Comment: @TaranjeetSingh Are you sure it isn't a redirect already cached by your browser? Run `curl -i abc123.ngrok.io` and check its output. Or better add that output to your question.

Comment: Oh yes that worked. But how could? I tried that earlier in incognito mode. Anyways, my bad. Thanks, i got that.